# Convert multiple json objects from a file into a list in python

Tags: python, json, list

I have multiple json nested objects which I fetched  from a file and cleansed as comma separated into a json file.

Ex:

```
{
“Key1” : “value1”,
“Key2” : “value2”, 
“Key3” : {
“Key4” : “value4”
}
},
{
“Key11” : “value11”,
“Key22” : “value22”, 
“Key33” : {
“Key44” : “value44”
}
}
```

How can I combine them into a list in python like below:

```
[{
“Key1” : “value1”,
“Key2” : “value2”, 
“Key3” : {
“Key4” : “value4”
}
},
{
“Key11” : “value11”,
“Key22” : “value22”, 
“Key33” : {
“Key44” : “value44”
}
}]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: as far as I know, `json` is a `dict`ionary, so it can't be just a `list` of `dict`s. Do you still have the objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to load the file as a string and append [ and ] before and after. then load the json.

```
content = "[" + content + "]"
json_content = json.loads(content)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import json

f1 = open('file.json', 'r', encoding='utf8')
data = f1.read()
print(json.loads('[' + data + ']'))
```